# Coinbase wallet 12 word seed used on metamask?

Tags: metamask, wallets, private-key, gas-price, coinbase

I have a couple of issues.

1. I have a Coinbase acct. I have a number of coins on there. And, of course I have the 12 word seed. If I use this 12 word seed and import it on metamask will all my coins show up from Coinbase wallet to metamask? Will they be risk at being lost on Coinbase wallet if I sign back in later?
2. If I import the 12 seeds onto metamask will I be able to still use and access my Coinbase wallet with the coins I still own?Can I use both Coinbase and metamask wallets interchangeably.

3.I have a item pending on etherscan. I tried to sell some PIKA (V1) for ETH on uniswap- the reason being is that PIKA is going to version 2 and I wish to get rid of before the swap happens otherwise the coins are rendered useless. I have Paid the gas fees for the initial swap and the transaction is still pending 12 hours later. I’ve read up that I must throw ETH in metamask and send back 0ETH (to my Coinbase ETH wallet address) to fix this issue? Is this true & correct.

4. I am also unable to send ETH out to another wallet of mine (as this tranaction) also pending. There seems to be a issue with Coinbase or something on etherscan getting that order finalised.

Ro

Answer (score 2):

[Ethereum seed phrases are based on BIP-39 standard](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). You can import the same seed phrase across multiple wallets. Some wallets might support only 12 or 24 word versions, but MyEtherWallet and MyCrypto support all formats.

You also have multiple questions in one question. It is not possible to mark questions answered. I suggest you open one question per question.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/98741/72389

But will I lose the coins if I try to put back in my Coinbase wallet?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some service do use BIP39 mnemonic passphrase BUT sometimes they are tweaking factors, for example PBKDF2 iteration, or key range.

For example, with Electrum (a bitcoin wallet) they are adding a seed version to your seed https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html.